# Radial solution of this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

can you guys give me an idea on how to begin solving this problem?

suppose $u(x,t)$ is smooth and solves

$u_{tt}(x,t)-4\Delta_{x}u(x,t)=0$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^{3}, t>0$

compute the radial solutions $u(x,t)=v(r,t), r=\sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{1}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}}$

Also, is $\Delta_{x}$ a typo? should it say just $\Delta$?

Comment: $\Delta_x$ refers to the fact that the Laplacian is taken with respect to the space variable $x$ and not the time variable $t$.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation

Answer (score 0):

In spherical coordinates, the Laplacian for a radially symmetric function $f=f(r)$ takes the form:

$$\Delta f = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}(rf).$$

So, if you search for a solution $v=v(r,t)$ then
$$
v_{tt} - 4\Delta v = v_{tt} - \frac{4}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}(rv)=0.$$

Multiplying by $r$, and noting that $rv_{tt} = (rv)_{tt}$, we have

$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}(rv) - 4 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}(rv)=0.$$

Changing variables: $u = rv$ it follows
$$
u_{tt} - 4u_{rr} =0,
$$
so that $u$ solves the 1D wave equation. General solutions to the 1D wave equation are

$u(r,t) = F(r-2t)+ G(r+2t),$

so we must have
$$
v(r,t) = \frac{1}{r}(F(r-2t)+G(r+2t)),
$$
where $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary.

Comment: maybe it should be $v(r,t)=1/r(F(r−4t)+G(r+4t))$? I didn't quite understand what you did with the 4.

Comment: I dropped the 4 in the equation with $u$. I have added it back in. You can check by plugging in $u$ into its equation that $F(r-2t)$ is the right expession: taking two $t$ derivatives will make $u_t = -2 F'$ and $u_{tt} = 4 F''$ while $u_{xx}=F''$.

Comment: Ok i got it, thanks.

Comment: By the way, using that last formula, and adding the initial conditions $u(x,0)=0,  u_{t}(x,0)=r$, how can I find the only solution to the first equation?